# conky manager korean break

Tags: conky, encoding, korean

I installed conky manager in ubuntu 18.04.
and, It pretty worked well and I costomized the color etc.
But, Korean Letters are broken.
how can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: are korean fonts installed on your OS?

Comment: And what font do you have in `.conkyrc`? Is it one that supports Korean characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer myself.
the default font that conky manager used wasn't supporting korean.
I fixed the config file and changed to a korean-supporting font.